# Criteria for displaying value on TextItem

Tags: smartgwt

When I select value from dropdown then other textitem should be updated.
Below is code for that:

```
SelectItem  courseItem = new SelectItem ("course.id", "Course");
courseItem.setOptionDataSource(CoursesDS.getInstance());

courseItem.setDisplayField("course.title");
courseItem.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                c.addCriteria("course.id", (Integer)event.getValue());
                CourseDS.getInstance().fetchData(c);
            }
        });

TextItem courseNameItem = new TextItem("course.title", "Course Name");
courseNameItem.setShowDisabled(false);
```

If i pass course id using criteria from selectitem then course name should automatically displayed in textitem but its not displaying.

please suggest where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the course id and do a fetch again.Instead of that in the courseSelectItem's changedHandler use getSelectedRecord method.Whenever the select item is changed the getSelectedRecord method will have the corresponding course record.From the selected record get course name and set it into text item

```
        final TextItem courseNameItem = new TextItem("course.title", "Course Name");
        courseNameItem.setShowDisabled(false);

        SelectItem courseItem = new SelectItem ("course.id", "Course");
        courseItem.setOptionDataSource(CoursesDS.getInstance());
        courseItem.setDisplayField("course.title");

        //Use changed handler
        courseItem.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) {
courseNameItem.setValue(courseItem.getSelectedRecord().getAttributeAsString("course.title"));
                }
            });
```